# Parameters are not considered by JMeter

Tags: java, spring, testing, jmeter, manual-testing

I'm new to JMeter.

I'm trying to test this endpoint manually using JMeter :

```java
@GetMapping("total-opportunities-value")
ResponseEntity<DashboardMetricDto> getTotalOpportunitiesValue(){}
```

that's the config I set to the Thread Group (same I use from postman) :

[image]

I don't know why the Authorization param is not considered because that's what I got in the logs of my app :

[image]

PS: the problem is not in the token !

JMeter Report

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're passing the "parameter" in the correct way.

Although it's possible to pass it as a [form-encoded body parameter](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6750#section-2.2)

my expectation is that you need to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/http-header-manager) and put it there in order to send it as a part of [Authorization](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) header :

[image]